How to update the latitude and longitude in SQL Server
UPDATE [Tree_Monitoring_Philips].[dbo].[T_NumberOfTrees]
SET [TreeLatitude] = '18°38'33.8352"',
    [TreeLongitude] = N'73°48'9.85"E' 
WHERE [ID] = 1

How to update the latitude & longitude in SQL server? The latitude and longitude are in degree per minutes seconds and SQL Server is enclosing the update query for minutes as per their defined update query format and does not get work the query.

Those look like strings, not geographic data, so you would update the value like any other string. Why do you feel that the fact the string represents a location changes that?

What are the actual data types of those columns? Regardless, the string literals you are using aren't valid as the ' in the middle needs to be escaped, e.g.: '18°38''33.8352"' instead of '18°38'33.8352"'.

It is unclear what data type your column has. What do you get when you SELECT TOP 1 TreeLatitude FROM Tree_Monitoring_Philips.dbo.T_NumberOfTrees? If you get a value like 18.642732, you likely have decimal degrees and will have to parse your value into separate degrees, minutes, and seconds values and then calculate decimal degrees as John Cappelletti described above. South latitudes and West longitudes are typically represented as negative values.

Is there any reason you are not using the built in geography datatype?

If you want to use DMS format you should use ('').
Here is the example,
SET [TreeLatitude] = '18°38''33.8352"',
    [TreeLongitude] = '73°48''9.85"E'


thank you!! I had the same issue and it fixed it @bsraskr

@walkingbas I am so glad to hear that worked for you!
